# IWhen I call post method filling json I get the same but in the fields everywhere null

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I haven't done anything programming related in a long time (5 days) and now I'm stupid

#### Code

**inMemoryStudentServiceImpl.java**

```java
package com.justdeax.coursepractice.Student;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class inMemoryStudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
    private final StudentDao repo;

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return repo.saveStudent(student);
    }

    @Override
    public Student findByEmail(String email) {
        return repo.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
        return repo.updateStudent(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(String email) {
        repo.deleteStudent(email);
    }
}
```

**StudentController.java**

```java
package com.justdeax.coursepractice.Student;

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/students")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentController {
    @NonNull
    private final StudentService services;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return services.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("save_student")
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return services.saveStudent(student);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{email}")
    public Student findByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        return services.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @PutMapping("update_student")
    public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
        return services.updateStudent(student);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("delete_student/{email}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable String email) {
        services.deleteStudent(email);
    }
}
```

**StudentService.java**

```java
package com.justdeax.coursepractice.Student;  
import java.util.List;  
public interface StudentService {  
    List<Student> findAll();  
    Student saveStudent(Student student);  
    Student findByEmail(String email);  
    Student updateStudent(Student student);  
    void deleteStudent(String email);  
}
```

**Student.java**

```java
package com.justdeax.coursepractice.Student;  
import lombok.*;  
import java.time.LocalDate;  
@Data  
@Builder  
public class Student {  
    private String firstName;  
    private String lastName;  
    private Integer age;  
    private LocalDate dataOfBirth;  
    private String email;  
}
```

**StudentDao.java**

```java
package com.justdeax.coursepractice.Student;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;  
  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.stream.IntStream;  
  
@Repository  
public class StudentDao {  
    private final List<Student> STUDENTS = new ArrayList<>();  
    public List<Student> findAll() {  
        return STUDENTS;  
    }  
  
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {  
        STUDENTS.add(student);  
        return student;  
    }  
  
    public Student findByEmail(String email) {  
        return STUDENTS.stream()  
                .filter(e -> e.getEmail().equals(email))  
                .findFirst()  
                .orElse(null);  
    }  
  
    public Student updateStudent(Student student) {  
        var studentIndex = IntStream.range(0, STUDENTS.size())  
                .filter(i -> STUDENTS.get(i).getEmail().equals(student.getEmail()))  
                .findFirst()  
                .orElse(-1);  
        if (studentIndex > -1) {  
            STUDENTS.set(studentIndex, student);  
            return student;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  
  
    public void deleteStudent(String email) {  
        var student = findByEmail(email);  
        if (student != null) STUDENTS.remove(student);  
    }  
}
```

#### Used:

- Lombok
- Spring Boot Starter Web
- Spring Boot Starter Test

#### Проблема:

When POST Request: localhost:8080/api/v1/students/save_student
This json is written:

```json
{
    "firstName": "abc",
    "lastName": "def",
    "age": "99",
    "dataOfBirth": "1000-10-10",
    "email": "abs@def.com"
}
```

After this request the response is output as the same json but everywhere is null, why?

```
{
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "age": null,
    "dataOfBirth": null,
    "email": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you receive a POST request with JSON data, you need to annotate the `@RequestBody` annotation in `saveStudent` method to let Spring know that the incoming JSON should be converted into a Student object

```
@PostMapping("save_student")
public Student saveStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return services.saveStudent(student);
}
```